# How to pull with rebase by default in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

By company policy, all pulls unless agreed with tech lead must be done with rebase rather than merge.

I use Eclipse and successfully set the default pull mode to rebase to all my branches (despite Eclipse suggests merge as default mode).

My deskmate, working on my same project, uses IntelliJ Idea. Guess what? He always forgets to check pull-with-rebase when pulling, ending up in endless merge commits.

I often have to complain with him for violating the rule I took so long to make a standard, then I need to do force pushing to fix the tree from the mess. Only 2 people here use IntelliJ, other use Eclipse and have no problems with Git.

How do I set the default pull mode in IntelliJ Idea?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

In IntelliJ you can set the default pull strategy in

```
File -> Settings -> Version Control -> Git
```

Change it under "Update method". There you can choose **"Rebase"** instead of **"Merge"**.

Comment: The problem with this config is that still doesn't work when used from VCS -> Git -> Pull, only works from VCS -> update project

Answer (score 6):

Leave alone IntelliJ IDEA. Run `git config --global pull.rebase true` in his git bash. Or set this on a per-branch basis, by `git config --global branch.<name>.rebase true`, which is safer and more flexible.

Comment: Actually the policy is that by default **any** branch must be rebased. Merges occur via pull requests or during large implementation campaigns resulting in a widely diverged tree.

Comment: This could be a good answer but actually it's not.
For developpers working with multiple environnements, using a global config on git is not a possible solution. For example xcode doesn't allow git rebase.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution that works for me in the IntelliJ IDEA 2018.3 Help documentation: [Rebase the current branch on top of another branch](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#rebase_branch_on_top_of_another_branch)

> **Rebase the current branch on top of another branch**
>
> 1. Invoke the branches popup and select the branch the you want to rebase the current branch onto.
> 2. Choose Rebase Current onto Selected from the list of available actions.